# Error while downloading multiple files from AWS S3 using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting error "File download failed with error write after end" while trying to download multiple files form AWS s3 using the below code snippet.

Can some one help me to figure out the root cause of the error?It would be great if any one can suggest a solution as well

Below code works without any issues if only a single file needs to be downloaded

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports.download = function (req, res) {

var S3_BUCKET = 'mybucketname'
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETKEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
});

var os = require('os');
var filenames = "file1.jpg,file2.jpg"

var str_array = filenames.split(','); 
for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    var filename = str_array[i].trim();

    localFileName = os.homedir() + "\\" + "Downloads" + "\\" + filename,

    file = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: filename
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        res.end("File download failed with error " + err.message);            
    })
    .on('httpData', function (chunk) {
        file.write(chunk);
    })
    .on('httpDone', function () {
        file.end();
    })
    .send();
}
  res.end("Files have been downloaded successfully")
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use `pipe` function rather than handle it manually.

```
s3.getObject(options)
    .createReadStream()
    .on('error', e => ...)
    .pipe(file)
    .on('error', e => ...);
```

Comment: I am wondering My code works fine for a single file download not with multiple files

Comment: Have you tried my code? About yours - try write `let file = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);` inside the loop.

Comment: what did you mean by using pipe? How does that fit into OP's example?